# Collapsible div height issue on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am facing a strange issue with the height of a collapsible div. The expanded height of the div remains, even after the div is closed / collapsed. Please refer the image below

[image]

The Javascript add the height to the li on click. For reference, here is the inspect element part.

```
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">

            <li><a target="_blank" href="www.somewebsite.com" data- 
   largesrc="uploadimage/project/sfs.jpg" data-title="Website Redesign of " 
   data-type="WebSite" data-description="Website Redesign "><img 
   src="uploadimage/project/thumb/sfs.jpg" alt="img00"></a></li>

   <li style="**transition: height 350ms ease 0s; height: 719px;**" 
 class="">
   <a href="#/" data-largesrc="uploadimage/project/notouch.jpg" data- 
  title="No Touch" data-type="Mobile Application" data-description="Notouch 
  is a simple but useful app that helps you to lock the screen temporarily 
  to prevent unauthorized clicks or to go to other apps from the current 
  screen. This is especially useful when you give your Phone to kids to view 
  videos or YouTube. This app will disable the touch facility temporarily."> 
  <img src="uploadimage/project/thumb/notouch.jpg" alt="img01"></a></li>

  <li><a target="_blank" href="www.fhjgh.com" data- 
  largesrc="uploadimage/project/2capture.jpg" data-title="Test" data- 
  type="WebSite" data-description="hI there njwehkasd kahffhsaf sdkfhsdf 
  saklhflkdshf sdhfksdhf kldsh"><img 
  src="uploadimage/project/thumb/2capture.jpg" alt="img02"></a></li>

  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.jhghjghjg.in" data- 
  largesrc="uploadimage/project/green.jpg" data-title="Green Homes" data- 
  type="WebSite" data-description=", due to better usage of pictures"><img 
  src="uploadimage/project/thumb/green.jpg" alt="img03"></a></li>

 <li><a href="#/" data-largesrc="uploadimage/project/leonardo.jpg" data- 
 title="Leonardo" data-type="Logo Design" data-description="The Logo design 
 . We have used the negative space design concept here to make the L hidden 
  inside a box ( Box represent a furniture)"><img 
 src="uploadimage/project/thumb/leonardo.jpg" alt="img04"></a></li>

</ul>
```

And the Javascript part ( which I believe) is this.

```
  open: function () {

        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            // set the height for the preview and the item
            this.setHeights();
            // scroll to position the preview in the right place
            this.positionPreview();
        }, this), 25);

    },
    close: function () {

        var self = this,
            onEndFn = function () {
                if (support) {
                    $(this).off(transEndEventName);
                }
                self.$item.removeClass('og-expanded');
                self.$previewEl.remove();
            };

        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {

            if (typeof this.$largeImg !== 'undefined') {
                this.$largeImg.fadeOut('fast');
            }
            this.$previewEl.css('height', 0);
            // the current expanded item (might be different from this.$item)
            var $expandedItem = $items.eq(this.expandedIdx);
            $expandedItem.css('height', $expandedItem.data('height')).on(transEndEventName, onEndFn);

            if (!support) {
                onEndFn.call();
            }

        }, this), 25);

        return false;

    },
    calcHeight: function () {

        var heightPreview = winsize.height - this.$item.data('height') - marginExpanded,
            itemHeight = winsize.height;

        if (heightPreview < settings.minHeight) {
            heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
            itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$item.data('height') + marginExpanded;
        }

        this.height = heightPreview;
        this.itemHeight = itemHeight;

    },
    setHeights: function () {

        var self = this,
            onEndFn = function () {
                if (support) {
                    self.$item.off(transEndEventName);
                }
                self.$item.addClass('og-expanded');
            };

        this.calcHeight();
        this.$previewEl.css('height', this.height);
        this.$item.css('height', this.itemHeight).on(transEndEventName, onEndFn);

        if (!support) {
            onEndFn.call();
        }

    },
    positionPreview: function () {

        // scroll page
        // case 1 : preview height + item height fits in window´s height
        // case 2 : preview height + item height does not fit in window´s height and preview height is smaller than window´s height
        // case 3 : preview height + item height does not fit in window´s height and preview height is bigger than window´s height
        var position = this.$item.data('offsetTop'),
            previewOffsetT = this.$previewEl.offset().top - scrollExtra,
            scrollVal = this.height + this.$item.data('height') + marginExpanded <= winsize.height ? position : this.height < winsize.height ? previewOffsetT - (winsize.height - this.height) : previewOffsetT;

        $body.animate({ scrollTop: scrollVal }, settings.speed);

    },
    setTransition: function () {
        this.$previewEl.css('transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing);
        this.$item.css('transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing);
    },
    getEl: function () {
        return this.$previewEl;
    }
}

return {
    init: init,
    addItems: addItems
};
```

})();

Please advice , how to resolve this issue. ( Is there a CSS or Javascript way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing at the end of the animation a command javascript: remove () on the container that contained the open image, or empty (). If you continue to see the wrong height even after trying these commands, it means that you have already left width / height attributes applied on the container, so you'll have to remove them, changing their value to ''.

Edit:

```
close: function () {
    ....
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {            
        document.getElementsByClassName('og-expander')[0].parentElement.removeAttribute("style");
        if (typeof this.$largeImg !== 'undefined') {
    ....
```

Already tested by me, it works.

Comment: The JS is applying an inline style to the clicked li (item) .. I think, That is actually causing the issue . <li style="transition: height 350ms ease 0s; height: 719px; class=""> . However the same is not getting removed, once the close button is clicked or the image is clicked (toggle)

Comment: Looking at the example you entered, it seems to me a problem due to the css. Removing the style and class attributes applied to the container should solve the problem, of course all at the end. Not being able to see the page in action I do not know how to act accurately, if I recreate a live example with the error I could solve it, but the code you entered is not enough for me, as I think it is a mistake of css, which is remedied with javascript by removing the remaining attributes.

Comment: Thank you . Please find the link here ( A website of mine http://test.viawebindia.com/portfolio)

Comment: I saw that closing the window remove the "og-expander" class from the <li>, correct, but you also have to remove the style attributes, try to insert before removing the class from <li> removeAttribute ("style").

Comment: Apologies, I did not get you correctly. Could you please explain a bit. Also this  line of code seems to apply the inline style to the items.

Comment: scrollVal = this.height + this.$item.data('height') + marginExpanded <= winsize.height ? position : this.height < winsize.height ? previewOffsetT - (winsize.height - this.height) : previewOffsetT;

        $body.animate({ scrollTop: scrollVal }, settings.speed);

    },
    setTransition: function () {
        this.$previewEl.css('transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing);
        this.$item.css('transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing);
    },

Comment: The following code closes the og expander function initItemsEvents($items) {
        $items.on('click', 'span.og-close', function () {
            hidePreview();
            return false;
            height('');
        }).children('a').on('click', function (e) {

            var $item = $(this).parent();
            // check if item already opened
            current === $item.index() ? hidePreview() : showPreview($item);
            return false;

        });

Comment: Thank you, should i append this call a separate function

Comment: Thank you very much; It works. I have uploaded the code.